# Finding cause of newRenderPipelineStateWithDescriptor failure

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I'm trying to create a pipeline state in swift and the app crashes with SIGABRT. I've put the call to `newRenderPipelineStateWithDescriptor` within a try catch block. Why is it not caching it?

Here's the code,

```
    let defaultLibrary = device.newDefaultLibrary()!
    let fragmentProgram = defaultLibrary.newFunctionWithName("passThroughFragment")!
    let vertexProgram = defaultLibrary.newFunctionWithName("passGeometry")!

    // check TexturedVertex
    let vertexDesc = MTLVertexDescriptor()
    vertexDesc.attributes[0].format = .Float3
    vertexDesc.attributes[0].offset = 0
    vertexDesc.attributes[0].bufferIndex = 0
    vertexDesc.attributes[1].format = .Float3
    vertexDesc.attributes[0].offset = sizeof(Vec3)
    vertexDesc.attributes[0].bufferIndex = 0
    vertexDesc.attributes[2].format = .Float2
    vertexDesc.attributes[0].offset = sizeof(Vec3) * 2
    vertexDesc.attributes[0].bufferIndex = 0
    vertexDesc.layouts[0].stepFunction = .PerVertex
    vertexDesc.layouts[0].stride = sizeof(TexturedVertex)


    let pipelineStateDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
    pipelineStateDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexProgram
    pipelineStateDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentProgram
    //pipelineStateDescriptor.vertexDescriptor = vertexDesc
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = view.colorPixelFormat
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].blendingEnabled = false
    pipelineStateDescriptor.sampleCount = view.sampleCount

    do {
        // SIGABRT will happen here when enabling .vertexDescriptor = vertexDesc
        try pipelineState = device.newRenderPipelineStateWithDescriptor(pipelineStateDescriptor)
    } catch let error {
        print("Failed to create pipeline state, error \(error)")
    }
```

The code above doesn't crash, until I enable this line,

```
pipelineStateDescriptor.vertexDescriptor = vertexDesc
```

To give a bit of background, my vertex shader used to receive a packed_float4 buffer as input but I'm trying to update it to a struct, as defined in the `MTLVertexDescriptor` above.

The frustrating thing is that the app just crashes without giving any hints of what's wrong.

Is there any way of get error messages when calling `device.newRenderPipelineStateWithDescriptor`?

Edit: 
This fixes the crash,

```
    vertexDesc.attributes[0].format = .Float3
    vertexDesc.attributes[0].offset = 0
    vertexDesc.attributes[0].bufferIndex = 0
    vertexDesc.attributes[1].format = .Float3
    vertexDesc.attributes[1].offset = sizeof(Vec3)
    vertexDesc.attributes[1].bufferIndex = 0
    vertexDesc.attributes[2].format = .Float2
    vertexDesc.attributes[2].offset = sizeof(Vec3) * 2
    vertexDesc.attributes[2].bufferIndex = 0
```

But apparently there's no way to make newRenderPipelineStateWithDescriptor to throw an exception because of that at the moment.

Comment: Aren't you modifying `vertexDesc.attributes[0]` too many times?

Comment: Oops! Copy-paste noob mistake! Thanks for spotting it :) That fixes the crash, but why is not the try-catch catching it? I thought Metal would be a bit more verbose than OpenGL ES... :/

Comment: Do not expect too much on do-catch of Swift, it just can catch only explicitly thrown errors. And then, why `newRenderPipelineStateWithDescriptor` does not detect all parameter inconsistency and explicitly throw errors? -- Maybe a trade-off, between time and space and/or some other things, or maybe just forgotten. Worth sending a [Bug Report](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/), I think.

Comment: If you tell the shader it should fetch all attributes from the same offset of the same buffer, it'll take you at your word and do it. There's not much in the way of validation that can save you here, since there are legitimate use cases where you might want to specify multiple attributes of differing types living at the same offset/stride.